# What is the limit of $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^x x^5}{x^x}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis

I am struggling with the evaluation of the following limit:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^x x^5}{x^x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^x}{x^{x-5}}.
$$
Intuitively I think the limit must be 0 since if $x$ is "very large" it must outpower $e^x$ by a long shot. But this is not really a rigorous explanation. I tried using the rule of l'Hopital but got nowhere since the terms just keep repeating. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hint: $x^x = \mathrm e^{x \ln(x)}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $x>e^2$, $x-5>0$, so $x^{x-5}>(e^2)^{x-5}$ and  $$0\leq\dfrac{e^x}{x^{x-5}}\leq \dfrac{e^x}{(e^2)^{x-5}}=\dfrac{e^x}{e^{2x-10}}=e^{-x+10}\to 0,$$ so the limit is indeed $0$.

Comment: Well... that actually makes a lot of sense to me so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For $x\ge 2e>5$ we have $${e^xx^5\over x^x}=\left ({e\over x}\right )^{x-5}e^{5}\le {1\over 2^{x-5}}e^5={(2e)^5\over 2^x}\to 0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^x}{x^{x-5}}&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^x}{e^{(x-5)\log x}}\\& = \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{x-(x-5)\log x}\\& = \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-x\log x+o(x\log x)}\\&=0\end{align} $$